# Connecting to Node Mongo API v3 using multiple hosts

Tags: node.js, mongodb

According to [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#standard-connection-string-format):

```
mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017,127.0.0.1:27017,127.0.0.1:27017/test
```

is a valid format. The latest Node driver requires the database name passed with the URI and the node docs refer to this page. However attempting to connect results in this error:

```
seed list contains no mongos proxies, replicaset connections requires the parameter replicaSet to be supplied in the URI or options object, mongodb://server:port/db?replicaSet=name
```

What is the correct format to pass multiple hosts to Mongo connect (Node mongodb 3.0.7)

Comment: Nothing in the documentation says using the same host address is valid. YES you can specify a "seed list" but this does not override the need to provide the `replicaSet` option. That `replicaSet` is the **actual** way the members are returned, the "list" are just "initial connections to try". Of course if you can support it then the ["DNS Seedlist Connection Format"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#dns-seedlist-connection-format) along with records in DNS with configuration for the `replicaSetName` and list of seeds and other config is generally preferred.

Comment: Another common misconception is the `/dbname` part of the connection string actually refers to the "Authentication Database" by convention on all modern driver implementations. There are still some legacy things around which take it to mean "default" database, but generally it's authentication and should be as `admin` by default ( and best practice ) and therefore "omitted" from the connection string entirely. Placing authentication details in different databases just leads to confusion.

Comment: @NeilLunn My Urls were just examples but your comment led me to see that the error stemmed from them being the same server, something I had not inferred from the error message.  Post that as the answer and I will mark.  Re 2nd comment - Node driver requires the database name of your "working" database as part of the URL nowadays. It cannot be omitted anymore.